# Showing Convergence in a Set of Sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $X$ be a vector space of real sequences and $l^2$ defined as

$$l^2=\left\{(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\in X : \sum^{\infty}_{k=1} |x_k|^2 < \infty \right\}.$$

Show that $l^2$ is complete.

---

So for showing completeness, I have to take an arbitrary Cauchy sequence of $l^2$ and show that it converges. My problem, however, is that $l^2$ seems to be a set of sequences. Therefore, its elements are sequences, so a Cauchy sequence of $l^2$ is a sequence of sequences (every member of the Cauchy sequence is a sequence as well). Now, if that is the case, how do I compute the distance between two sequences?

In other words, if $(((x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}})_l)_{l\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence, is the following correct?

$$\left|\left(\left(x_k\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\right)_m-\left(\left(x_k\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\right)_n\right|<\epsilon$$

Do I then, for completeness, have to show this?

$$\left|\left(x_k\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}-\left(\left(x_k\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\right)_n\right|<\epsilon$$

If the things above are true, how do I compute the distance of two sequences? Am I overthinking it? I hope I could make my question clear. In general, I'm just not sure how to tackle sequences in a set of sequences.

Comment: Are you aware what the norm on $\ell^{2}$ is? If not, it is $\|x\|_{2} = (\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|^2)^{1/2}$. If we denote some Cauchy sequence $x^{(n)}$, then you want to prove that the coordinate-wise limit $x \in \ell^{2}$ exists, and that $x^{(n)}$ converges to $x$. The last part you prove by showing that $\|x - x^{(n)}\|_{2} \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Ah, I understand. The norm you gave me was given, but I wasn't too sure if it was important for showing completeness. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance between two $\ell^2$ sequences is their difference in the $\ell^2$ norm:
$$ d((x_n), (y_n)) = \lVert (x_n) - (y_n) \rVert _2 = \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |x_k-y_k|^2}$$

Comment: Thank you for the help. I understood it now.